# Can I use type declaration files from node_modules without importing the actual modules?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tensorflow.js, type-declaration

I am loading the *teachable machine* image library using a script tag:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@teachablemachine/image@0.8/dist/teachablemachine-image.min.js"></script>
```

In my typescript project, I use the `tmImage` code as follows:

```
let model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL)
```

Which gives this error in Typescript:

```
cannot find name `tmImage`
```

So I need type declaration files, which are not available on https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/, but ARE available in the actual module. So I installed it using:

```
npm install @teachablemachine/image
```

Now, inside **node_modules** there are a lot of cross-referencing `.d.ts` files that contain all needed type information.

I assumed that Visual Studio Code would automatically pick up all information from `.d.ts` files in my project, but this only happens when I actually `import` the modules with:

```
import * as tmImage from '@teachablemachine/image';
```

Now the types ARE recognised very nicely with code completion, but I also need to compile the teachable machine code along with my own code!

Is it possible to use only the type information from **node_modules** during development time, or do I need to abandon my `<script>` tag and compile all the `teachable machine` code myself, only because I use Typescript?

Answer (score 1):

You are not compiling the library every time, you are just importing it. The library is already compiled inside node_modules. So you can use the imports and exclude them *from your bundler* if you are using one.

If you want the types globally available you need to add a `.d.ts` file to your project. TS doesn't assume a type is available just because it is on the node_modules, but you can add that by extending the global namespace like this:

```js
// In a `.d.ts` file within the included folders of your project
import * as _tmImage from '@teachablemachine/image';

declare global {
    const tmImage: typeof _tmImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. But how can I exclude `imports` from the build? Is there no way to just use the `.d.ts` files that are already available in the `node_modules` folder without importing? (Because my other `.d.ts` files also don't need an `import` statement).

Comment: You can also include that `.d.ts` file in your tsconfig under includes, that should work too